# how to create parameter file in C program and use it in main c file

Tags: c

i have one parameter file ex.

```
A1
{
 x1 = 10
 x2 = 23
 ..............
}
A2
{
 x1 = 34
 x2 = 54
 .................
}
...........
```

Above information will be in file1.c and i want to use those values in my another C file program.
could any one give me the proper sysntax in C.

Comment: have you tried anything? post your effort and problems you are facing in your work.

Comment: You need to read and parse this parameter file at run time. Reading about [File handling in C](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=file+handling+in+C&aq=f&oq=file+handling+in+C) should help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

parameter.h :

```
struct parameter {
    int x1;
    int x2;
    //...
};

extern struct parameter A[];
```

parameter.c :

```
#include "parameter.h"

struct parameter A[] = {
    [1] = { .x1 = 10, .x2 = 23 },
    [2] = { .x1 = 34, .x2 = 54 },
};
```

main.c :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "parameter.h"

int main(void){
    printf("%d\n", A[1].x1);
    printf("%d\n", A[2].x2);
    return 0;
}
```

`gcc main.c parameter.c -o prog`